# Target li a Jasny navbar-offcanvas

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started with Ruby on Rails. I've added the gem 'jasny-bootstrap-rails' and I'm using the Jasny OffCanvas nav menu which looks like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 18px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navbar-offcanvas" data-canvas="body">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JacobHedengren.ME</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-offcanvas offcanvas">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navmenu/">Slide in</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navmenu-push/">Push</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navmenu-reveal">Reveal</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Off canvas navbar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

I wanted my OffCanvas expanded menu in a different background color which I've managed to change using:

```
.navmenu-default, .navbar-default .navbar-offcanvas {
background-color: #3F51B5 !important;
border-color: #3F51B5 !important;
}
```

The problem is though that it requires a different li a color. **EDIT: The "desktop" navbar li a and the mobile nav li a should have different colors** Any idea how I would change the li a color for the OffCanvas expanded menu? I've tried all css tricks I know of. I guess it could be done with javascript but how would I do that?

Jasny: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/

**EDIT:** **The menu:** http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navbar-offcanvas/

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I'm understanding correctly, you want the `<li>` to be a different color than the default.

Something like this?

```
@media screen and (max-width:760px){
  .navbar-default .navbar-offcanvas li a{
      color:red; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aarmora. Thanks for your reply. No, See this example: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navbar-offcanvas/  I want the "desktop" navbar li a and the "mobile/expanded" navbar li a to have different colors.

Comment: @jacobhed so it's two different sets of html or are there media queries changing the nav?

Comment: I think the problem is that they share the same html. When I expand the menu in mobile the background color of the menu is different than when viewed in desktop. But the menu when viewed in mobile should have a different li a color. How would I changed that?

Comment: @jacobhed See my edit.  What if you add a media query based on whenever it become mobile?  In my example I assume 760px.

Comment: Thanks. Its strange it doesn't work. I guess there is something beyond my knowledge I need to do...

Comment: @jacobhed so using the media query didn't solve the problem?  Using a media query on the example page you sent me did work (if I'm understanding the issue).

Comment: All of a sudden your solution worked Aarmora! Thanks alot. Strangely it didn't work the first 5 times I tried it. Thanks alot for your help!